# How to identify when user phone call is in progress using ionic or cordova?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic3

How to identify when user phone call is in progress?

Is there any cordova or ionic plugins available? Or it can be done via some alternative ways?

Comment: I've never used it but this plugin might help you: [cordova-phone-call-trap](https://github.com/renanoliveira/cordova-phone-call-trap). With this you can get events about incoming calls.

Answer (score 0):

We can trigger phonecall using cordova plugin 'cordova-plugin-call-number'. But we can't get the progress of the call. It's not in the device control, it will fall under Mobile N/w Providers.